# Trying to returned the 2nd last position of a matched value

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, indexing, match

As it is really difficult to make understand the problem. I have uploaded the pic. It might help you to understand my problem. Please help me to solve it out. Thanks in advance 
[image]

Comment: Please explain why column D is the correct position. I can make no sense of it.

Comment: So the need is getting the latest position of the letter in column B **before** the current position of this letter? But then why the values in D1:D3 as there are not positions before? This values should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reconcile why you would want to have the pattern in column D. It seems to be *'look up the first position for the first two matches then progressive positions for the remainder of any matches'*.

Here is the solution to your problem.

In D1, as a standard formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$12)/(B$1:B$12=B1), COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)-(COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)>1))
'to retrieve the values from column A as,
=INDEX(A:A AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$12)/(B$1:B$12=B1), COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)-(COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)>1)))
```

However, I strongly suspect that it should be closer to this (as in G1),

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$12)/(B$1:B$12=B1), COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)-(COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)>1))
'to retrieve the values from column A as,
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$12)/(B$1:B$12=B1), COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)-(COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1)>1)))
```

---

[image: weird_progressionG]

Comment: Actually I wanted to have the pattern in Column E. Anyways thanks a lot for solving this.

Comment: Hi Jeeped I have another question; in the same sheet I have applied the following formula:
=IF(B4=$B$2:B3,"T","F")
and having #VALUE! error. Why do you know??

Comment: Use [ctrl]+[shift]+[delete] as that is an array formula. It might be better as `=countif(b$2:b3, b4)>1`. I'm not entirely sure what results you expect.

Comment: i am trying to save two different values for B4. if the value of B4 matches within the range B1 to B3 then I want to save T and if doesn't match then I want to save F.
your code is right but I am trying to have values from two different columns not True or False.